# Date Criteria in PS Query

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I have this criteria for my PS Query:

*Admission Data Creation (Date)
This is a FROM date. All records starting from the selected date to the current date will be included in the report. Leaving this blank will default this to the current date.*

And I made the query below:

```
  WHERE ( ( A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
     AND A.EMPLID = E.EMPLID 
     AND H.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(H_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_ACAD_PROG_CAF H_ED 
        WHERE H.INSTITUTION = H_ED.INSTITUTION 
          AND H.ACAD_PROG = H_ED.ACAD_PROG 
          AND H_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
     AND A.EMPLID = C.EMPLID 
     AND C.INSTITUTION = A.INSTITUTION 
     AND C.INSTITUTION = D.INSTITUTION 
     AND C.SAD_UC_APPCODE = D.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
     AND C.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = D.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
     AND C.INSTITUTION = F.INSTITUTION 
     AND C.SAD_UC_APPCODE = F.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
     AND C.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = F.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
     AND F.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_UM_CTXT_PERCTXT F_ED 
        WHERE F.INSTITUTION = F_ED.INSTITUTION 
          AND F.SAD_UC_APPCODE = F_ED.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
          AND F.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = F_ED.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
          AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
    AND F.EFFSEQ = 
        (SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_UM_CTXT_PERCTXT F_ES 
        WHERE F.INSTITUTION = F_ES.INSTITUTION 
          AND F.SAD_UC_APPCODE = F_ES.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
          AND F.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = F_ES.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
          AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) 
     AND D.INSTITUTION = G.INSTITUTION 
     AND D.SAD_UC_PERS_ID = G.SAD_UC_PERS_ID 
     AND D.SAD_UC_APPCODE = G.SAD_UC_APPCODE 
     AND D.SAD_UC_CHOICENO = G.SAD_UC_CHOICENO 
     AND H.SCC_CAF_ATTR_SEQ = 1 
     AND H.SCC_CAF_ATTRIB_NM = 'UM_MDAS_MAP' 
     AND H.SCC_CAF_ATTR_VAL IN ('MAP','MDAS') 
     AND G.SAD_UC_ABBREVCODE = 'AC' 
     AND F.UM_CTXT_WP_FLAG = 'Y' 
     AND F.UM_CTXT_WPPLS_FLAG = 'Y' 
     AND A.INSTITUTION = :1 
     AND ( A.ACAD_CAREER = :2 
     OR ' ' = :2) 
     AND 1 = 1 AND (  A.EMPLID = :4
OR ' ' = :4) 
     AND ( TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NULL 
     OR A.ADM_CREATION_DT >= 
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
     AND A.ADM_CREATION_DT <= 
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') )) 
  ORDER BY 1, 5, 2, 6
```

The part of the criteria above if you can see is this one:

```
     AND ( TO_DATE(:3,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NULL 
     OR A.ADM_CREATION_DT >= 
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
     AND A.ADM_CREATION_DT <= 
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') ))
```

The problem is it just doesn't pull what I want, I tried different ways of doing this but gets something like a date format error. Been with this problem since last week. Really need help on how to add the criteria to my PS Query.

Comment: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')` can be simplified to `trunc(sysdate)`. What is the data type of `A.ADM_CREATION_DT`?

Comment: ADM_CREATION_DT is date type

Comment: Is the problem wrong results or an error?

Comment: Using that above I cant pull any results. I tried changing that part but there seem to be something wrong with the update with regards to the format of ADM_CREATION_DT.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson hey man I have a new problem, when leaving the field blank how do you make it default to current date.

Comment: [`coalesce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COALESCE.html) or [`nvl`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NVL.html) maybe.

Comment: I get this error:

 
Institution : UMANC

Rerun Query
A SQL error occurred. Please consult your system log for details.
Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=8006, Message=Invalid datatype specified (50,380)